# Identify average file size of MimeType in directory

Tags: java

I am scanning a directory by its MimeTypes. So far, my code counts the total amount of existing MimiTypes in the directory:

```
File dir = new File(dirPath);
File[] files = dir.listFiles((FileFilter) HiddenFileFilter.VISIBLE);

ArrayList<String> mimeArray = new ArrayList<String>();

if (files.length == 0) {
    System.out.println("The directory is empty");
 } else {
     for (File aFile : files) {
        mimeArray.add(mtftp.getContentType(aFile));
      }

Map<String, Long> counts =
            mimeArray.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()));
```

I would like to sum the file sizes by appearing MimeTypes and divide it by amount to get the average size of each MimeType.
But how can I implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
File dir = new File(dirPath);
File[] files = dir.listFiles((FileFilter) HiddenFileFilter.VISIBLE);

Map<String, ArrayList<Long>> mimeArray = new HashMap();

if (files.length == 0) {
    System.out.println("The directory is empty");
} 
else {
     for (File aFile : files) {
         if (!mimeArray.keySet().contains(mtftp.getContentType(aFile))) {
             mimeArray.put(mtftp.getContentType(aFile), 0L);
         }
         mimeArray.get(mtftp.getContentType(aFile)) += aFile.length;
     }
}
```

Edited because old version was not doing exactly what you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Do an iteration over your result mimeArray, sum up the file-sizes (file.lenght()) and divide by the number of results.

Comment: But mimeArray includes only the MimeType and the number of its appearance. I need an iteration which filters the existing MimeTypes  successively to sum up the file sizes in the directory.